# Infinite Sub Category Ordering in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Given [this table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6a89/1)

Is it possible to write SQL to write a SELECT query that would result in an order such as this, while also being applicable regardless the number of subcategories in the table? I can write queries to fetch the correct order with a hard coded number of expected subcategories but I run into difficulty when that number is unknown.

```
Miscellaneous
Personal
    Bobby
    Jane
    Susie
    Tom
    Other
        Work Lunches
```

Or would I have to adjust the schema?

Comment: Could you share the query you have please ? Also can you simply not have  SELECT statement where you order by PARENTID ASC ?

Comment: @Steve's answer is along the right lines, but if you want to know how to handle trees in sql properly for your situation you need [Joe Celko](http://www.amazon.com/Hierarchies-Smarties-Edition-Kaufmann-Management/dp/0123877334)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the best way is to manage the hierarchical data via the "Nested set" model:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

it may seem alien first, but it is just fantastic once you get your head around it. (Yes I am using it, and it works great)

Of course this means you have to change your schema a bit (include the left & right values) and the selects/inserts/updates are different.  But you can select or re-attach whole branches in one go very easily.

Comment: The problem with left and right values is when you want to add something to the middle of the tree, you have to recalculate all your elements.

Comment: Indeed, delete/insert and move operations involve a bit of extra fiddling.   So if you have a tree structure that changes often, this maybe a problem.  But most of these structures are menus that are read 1000's of times before they're updated once.  And in that case it's beneficial.